# Access Linux Folder from Local System account on Windows PC

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking

I have a TV recording services that run on my Windows PC under the [Local System] account.

I have a networked media folder on a Linux file server.

My home network is not on a domain.

I don't have a an authentication protocol running on my network's *WORKGROUP*.

Right now, I can't record to the networked media folder because the [Local System] account does not have access.

### How do I go about giving [Local System] account on the Windows PC access to the networked Linux folder?

Comment: Please add more details; how is the media folder "networked"? Samba/cifs or nfs? Is it a regular linux system serving as file server? Or is a dedicated nas system? Can you connect the share and is the problem that you can't write to it? Or can't you access it at all? If so can you ping the file server?

Comment: @Bram, I don't know enough about Linux to understand what you are asking. The drive is EXT4 format. The path is `\\DIETPI\dietpi`.

Comment: This may solve my issues: http://superuser.com/a/274799/65442